# require process bar with percentage in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

suppose i have one example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

in this example , i am getting data into `<div id="myDiv"></div>` from "demo_get.jsp".Suppose I am getting some random seconds(i.e 5,10,15 sec) to load data in "myDiv". so, instead of waiting for this time i need to display one process bar with percentage info. is this possible ?

Comment: Short answer, no it's not possible. HTTP is stateless, so you know when you made the request and you know when the request ends. You *cannot* know how far through the request is while it is happening. To do something like that, you would need to look at using sockets.

Comment: Why not use a spinner...or gif image...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can u suggest me another way so i can complete my work.

Comment: I already did - websockets.